# Why does !== work in my facotrchain function, but not === in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, return, conditional-statements

Why is it that the following code works when I use !== in the conditional statement,

```js
function factorChain(arr) {
  //iterate through array
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i+1] % arr[i] !== 0){
      return false;
    } 
  }
  //check to see if previous element is a factor of current element
  //if so, return true
  return true;
}
console.log(factorChain([2, 4, 6, 7, 12]));
```

but when I change it to === as in the second section of code, it does not work.

```js
function factorChain(arr) {
    //iterate through array
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i+1] % arr[i] === 0){
      return true;
    } 
  }
  //check to see if previous element is a factor of current element
  //if so, return true
  return false;
}
console.log(factorChain([2, 4, 6, 7, 12]));
```

Comment: returning `false` for one false test is not the same as returning `true` for one true test. the first example ensures _all_ tests are false before returning `true`, the second example returns `true` if just _one_ of the tests are true.

Comment: In the second example the `return true` abruptly ends the function so if for any iteration if `return true` is called the entire function returns true, the same applies if you `return false` because `return` immediately ends the function

Comment: Hello Natasha, and welcome on SO. If you expect your function to act as your comment, I'd say that your second answer is invalid because it will return permaturly once it find one occurence of a modulo that matches.

Comment: return true stops the function execution. So, your function has been ended and it would not executing.

Comment: fwiw `const factorChain = arr => arr.every((x, i, a) => !(a[i+1]%x));`

Answer (score 0):

Returning `false` for one false test is not the same as returning `true` for one true test. The first example ensures all tests are false before returning `true`, whereas the second example returns `true` if just one of the tests are true.

I'll show another way to write `factorChain` as a recursive function using [inductive reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) -

1. if the input array, `arr`, has less than 2 elements, return the base result, `true`.
2. (inductive) the input has at least two elements. if the first element is a factor of the second element, return the result of the sub-problem `arr.slice(1)`.
3. (inductive) the input has at least two elements and the first element is *not* a factor of the second element. return `false`.

```js
function factorChain (arr)
{ if (arr.length < 2)
    return true                       // 1
  else if (arr[1] % arr[0] === 0)
    return factorChain(arr.slice(1))  // 2
  else
    return false                      // 3
}

console.log(factorChain([ 2, 4, 8, 24, 96 ])) // true
console.log(factorChain([ 2, 4, 8, 20, 40])) // false
```

[Propositional logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus) is governed by many laws that allow us to manipulate logical expressions and maintain correctness. We can collapse the logical branches 2 and 3 using logical **and**, `&&` -

```js
function factorChain (arr)
{ if (arr.length < 2)
    return true
  else
    return arr[1] % arr[0] === 0 && factorChain(arr.slice(1))
}

console.log(factorChain([ 2, 4, 8, 24, 96 ])) // true
console.log(factorChain([ 2, 4, 8, 20, 40])) // false
```

And we can collapse branches 1 and 2 using logical **or**, `||` -

```js
const factorChain = arr =>
  arr.length < 2 || arr[1] % arr[0] === 0 && factorChain(arr.slice(1))

console.log(factorChain([ 2, 4, 8, 24, 96 ])) // true
console.log(factorChain([ 2, 4, 8, 20, 40])) // false
```